# Binding value to TextInput with data from Another Screen - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass data to another screen using `navigation`, seems not to be working:

```
 componentDidMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const phoneNumber = navigation.getParam('phoneNumber');

  this.setState({phoneNumber: phoneNumber });  
}
```

view:

```
<Input value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChangeText={(phoneNumber) => this.setState({phoneNumber})} />
```

Comment: what the meaning of "not working"? you don't get `phoneNumber` in didMount or you cant change state `onChangeText`? how do you set `phoneNumber` navigation param?

Comment: I get phoneNumber, but it doesn't bind to the Input.

Comment: Are you using `TextInput` component? Cause at your code you attached `Input` but at question title you wrote `TextInput`

Comment: I am using Input

Comment: Where are you importing the 'Input' from is this a custom component ?

Comment: I am using native-base